# When heroku going to install in terminal, it shows an error says "heroku is not recognize". any solution?

Tags: node.js

*heroku : The term 'heroku' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- heroku login*

The above error show when try to login in heruko using terminal.Any solution?

Comment: [did you install the heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-the-heroku-cli)?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is not installed. Install npm then heroku